# Need help on printing doubles and char value

Tags: java, println

package trigFunctions;

import java.text.*;

public class FunctionsApplied {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    double sinx = 0.0;
    double cosx = 0.0;
    double tanx = 0.0;
    double cotx = 0.0;
    double secx = 0.0;
    double cscx = 0.0;

    final double piradiansconversion = 0.0174532925; //setting up variables

    System.out.println("sin x        cos x        tan x        cot x        sec x        csc x");//gives labels to each answer

    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("0000.0000");

    for(double counter = 0.00000; counter<=360; counter +=.1)
    {
        sinx= piradiansconversion*counter;//converts to radians
        sinx= Math.sin(sinx);//calculates sin


        cosx= piradiansconversion*counter;//converts to radian
        cosx= Math.cos(cosx);//calculates cos

        if(cosx > 0.0000005)
            tanx= sinx / cosx;//finds tan x
        else
            tanx= (char)'-';

        if(sinx > 0.0000005)
            cotx= cosx/sinx;//finds cot x
        else 
            cotx= (char)'-';

        if(cosx > 0.0000005)
            secx= 1/cosx;//finds sec x
        else
            secx= (char)'-';

        if(sinx > 0.0000005)
            cscx= 1/sinx;//finds csc x
        else
            cscx= (char)'-';



        System.out.println(df.format(sinx)+"    "+df.format(cosx)+"    "+df.format(tanx)+"    "+df.format(cotx)+"    "+df.format(secx)+"    "+df.format(cscx));//prints answers in columns and formats code to 4 decimal places
    }


}
```

}

// ok so my problem is on the output it will not print the char value '-', instead it prints the number value. the formatting works as I am trying to have 4 numbers before the decimal point and 4 numbers after the decimal point. What is not working is on the if/else statement where I assign my variable (char)'-' if the denominator is less than .0000005     Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the `double` value `tanx` is always a number.  The reason that you can assign the `char` `'-'` to it is that Java allows a primitive widening conversion from the Unicode value of the `char` to wider primitive types, such as `double`.  Even if you are casting the `char` to a `char` with `(char)`, the value will still be widened to a `double` upon assignment to a `double`.

Instead of maintaining `double` values to print later, maintain `String` values to print later.

Once calculated, immediately format the value as a `String` to assign to `tanx`, which should be declared as a `String`.  Then assign `"-"` to `tanx`.  (The other result variables should now be `String`s also.)

Comment: Can give me some example code so I can better understand what you are saying.

Answer (score 0):

I did it a different way. I set up the System.out.print() in the if/ else statements and simply printed something similar to System.out.print("-") in the else statements. It's a work around to what I was originally trying to do but eh, it works.

`if(cosx > 0.0000005)//checks if the denominator is less than .0000005
                {
                tanx= sinx / cosx;//finds tan x
                System.out.print((df.format(tanx))+"    ");
                }
            else
                System.out.print("  "+lessthan+"      ");//prints - if the denominator is less that 0.0000005`

i set up a char variable containing '-' just because I wanted to. I realize it is an unnecessary step. Thanks for your response though. I still want to see an example code of what you are talking about if you dont mind.